# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null

Tags: java, swing, exception

I want to display a random image in this program when the button is clicked but i get an exception error and cant fix it.

```
public class TestImage1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String sonido = "Windows Navigation Start.wav";
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido);
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
        try {
            TestImage1 obj = new TestImage1();
            obj.run(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        imgRandom form = new imgRandom();
        form.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);
        form.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class imgRandom extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private JLabel label2;
        JButton boton;
        String cads[] = {"/img/duck.gif", "/img/luigi.png", "/img/mario.jpg"};

        public imgRandom() throws IOException {
            setLayout(null);
            label2 = new JLabel("press");
            label2.setBounds(10, 20, 100, 100);
            add(label2);

            boton = new JButton("Presioname!!");
            boton.setBounds(150, 250, 200, 100);
            add(boton);
            boton.addActionListener(this);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == boton) {
                int ra = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
                URL url = this.getClass().getResource(cads[ra]);
                try {
                    Image img = ImageIO.read(url);
                    label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

can sombedy tell me how to fix it. if the button is pressed it should display a random image but it throws an exception with a lot of other error.

Comment: `setLayout(null);` Why did you do this?

Answer (score 2):

In your code there might be some issues while getting the images.

I have already posted some answers in the same context that might help you.

- [How to retrieve image from project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)
- [Read image from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478984/read-image-from-another-directory/23479127#23479127)

---

#### Some points:

1. Don't use `null` layout instead use proper layout that's why they are designed for.

   Read more [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)
2. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure that [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) is initialized properly.

   Read more

   - [Why to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302085/why-to-use-swingutilities-invokelater-in-main-method)
   - [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196889/swingutilities-invokelater)
3. Don't extend any class until and unless you are modifying the existing logic.

   Read more

   - [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: +1, `In your code there might be some issues while getting the images.` - the code works fine for me, so would also guess this is the problem.