# ImageIcon does not work with me

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

i wrote very simple code to display an icon of the grapes but still the code doesn't show me anything

here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Code {
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("image/grapes2.jpg");
JLabel label = new JLabel("Grapes", ii, SwingConstants.CENTER);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImageIcon");

public void ui(){
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label.setIconTextGap(5);

    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    frame.setSize(2300,2300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(label);

}
```

}

Comment: where is the image placed ?

Comment: have you place image in images directory and in which directory your java file is ?

Comment: there is a file in the same project file .. that file named "imege"

Comment: It should be `image` instead of `imege`. Simply re-size the frame and look what happens.

Comment: sorry .. it is image .. spelling mistake .. my bad ** + i re-sized it but nothing happened. Same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If image icon is not visible even after calling `frame.setVisible(true)` in the end then have a look at my another posts that is asked in the same context.

- [How to retrieve image from project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)
- [Read image from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478984/read-image-from-another-directory/23479127#23479127)

---

Try

```
// Read from src/image folder
ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image/grapes2.jpg")));
label.setIcon(ii);
```

---

It's worth reading [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) and here is the sample directly from there.

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif",
                             "a pretty but meaningless splat");
label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text", icon, JLabel.CENTER);
...
label3 = new JLabel(icon);

/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                           String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Read more [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) where it is explained visually.

For e.g. Class file in directory named omega. Image in `omega/images` directory.

[image]