# Loading an image from folder in project

Tags: java, image, path, imageicon

I am currently working on a text-based RPG with a GUI and I can't seem to get the image I want to use to load.

```
class BackgroundPanel extends Panel
{
    // The Image to store the background image in.
    Image img;
    public BackgroundPanel(String location)
    {
        // Loads the background image and stores in img object.
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(location);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // Draws the img to the BackgroundPanel.
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        img.setAccelerationPriority(SCALE_FAST);
    }
}
```

This is the code I use for the panel itself. I tried putting the image file in the root directory of my project but it doesn't seem to help. I have created a folder within the project which I intend to use for all of my images.

I'm not sure what the issue is here. I know I tried using `paint()` instead of `paintComponent()`, but then the buttons and other components won't draw until you mouse over them, for some reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `extends JPanel`

Comment: Add the @Override annotation to the paintComponent method. This should help identify the problem. There is never any reason why paintComponent should be public

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted it at below links in the same context. Please have a look:

- [ImageIcon does not work with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217961/imageicon-does-not-work-with-me?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [How to retrieve image from project folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744920/how-to-retrieve-image-from-project-folder/22746825#22746825)
- [Read image from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478984/read-image-from-another-directory/23479127#23479127)

---

It's already described in *Oracle Java Tutorial* on [Loading Images Using getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource)

**Note:** Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()` in the overridden `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: Hi Braj . currently i am loading the image as `FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("D:/Logo.jpg"));` is it possible to load from my project structure . something like `File(/webappName/images)` ?

Comment: Is it a web project or just a standalone swing project? Are you using it inside the Applet? Have you tried all the links that I shared you from my another posts?

Comment: It is a spring web application project . i looked at your posts it is more of swing . can you pls help me ?

Comment: In web application, you should use Application Context to get the real path of the resources that reside inside the war. Try [ServletContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Can you pls describe it or link an example

Comment: here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623709/output-an-image-file-from-a-servlet)